# Can 'BrokerNotAvailableException' happen during producing a Kafka message?

Tags: apache-kafka

I see 'BrokerNotAvailableException' from the below list http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/errors/BrokerNotAvailableException.html

but I don't see this in the exceptions for a Callback.
https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback.html

Does it mean, BrokerNotAvailableException will not happen when using Callback?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: I don't see where this exception might get thrown. Have you guys figured it out?

Comment: And Javadoc says nothing about it